# jQuery ajaxForm success: access the form

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I'm using jQuery Form plugin (https://github.com/malsup/form):

```
$("#dlgTask form").ajaxForm({
    success: function(res) {
        var form = this;
    }
});
```

In `success` function, `form` variable seems an object other than the form itself. How to access the form, so I can avoid using `$("#dlgTask form")` again for reusability? Thanks.

Comment: access the form object , whats the problem ?

Comment: how is it other than using `$("#dlgTask form")` again? that's what i'm asking :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The success' callback function has a [4th argument for your jQuery-wrapped form element](https://github.com/malsup/form#success).

```
$("#dlgTask form").ajaxForm({
    success: function(res, status, xhr, form) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

You can also simply store your form element before using ajaxForm()

```
var form = $("#dlgTask form");
form.ajaxForm({
    success: function(res) {
        // ... 
    }
});
```

Comment: The 1st (success callback's 4th param) is what I'm looking for. How could I miss reading the page? :-) Thanks.